# Embedding font in a Java program using iText

Tags: java, fonts, itext, truetype

I want to embed font into my Java program and I know how to do  it using standard Java libraries. However, how do I do it using iText?

I don't want anything outside of my project (or later jar file) to be tampered with if it's not absolutely necessary (I want my program to work on all Java supporting platforms).

I'm importing font using `*.ttf` file.

Comment: How do you want to embed a font into Java program?

Comment: In a way that the platform my program is running on doesn't have to have it installed...

Comment: Is this a platform dependent?

Comment: Windows (7)
I have a fontname.ttf file using which I want to create a font that iText will stick into a PDF, instead of locating the file on the platform, since there's always a chance that the file (or font) coud not exist on that platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a font

```
public static String[] FONT = 
    {"path/to/fonts/xxx.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI};
```

then use

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT[0], FONT[1], BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bf, 24);
```

with the document.

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333018/creating-fonts-from-ttf-files-using-itext